# Menu hook callbacks not working for anonymous users

Tags: 7, hooks, navigation

My custom error handler module is somewhat based on the [customerror](https://www.drupal.org/project/customerror) module, but instead of returning markup, my menu callback function redirects based on the original path. It registers error paths as follows:

```
function my_customerror_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['my_customerror/%'] = array(
    'title callback' => FALSE,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'my_customerror_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

`'access callback' => TRUE` should make it accessible to all users. I can use the path `my_customerror/404` for example in the site settings and it is recognized as a valid path. This works fine in a local instance and on the Pantheon development  site, but once I pushed it to the Pantheon test environment, `my_customerror/404` is not invoked on 404 - Drupal uses the default error response. Unless I am logged in, then it works in Test as well.

But the path `my_customerror/404` works regardless when I type it in manually and does what it should. Somehow Drupal erroneously thinks that this path is not accessible to anonymous users.

What could be causing this?

Here is a simplified version of the callback function that shows what it does:

```
function my_customerror_page($code) {
  $dest = variable_get('my_customerror_' . $code . '_default', '');
  switch ($code) {
    [conditional stuff]
    default:
      header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);
      header("Location: " . $dest);
      break;
  }
  return "";
}
```

Don't ask why I use header() and not drupal_goto() ....

Just bringing something into the problem description that I already mentioned in a comment. When the Devel module is turned on and anonymous users are given permission to see developer output, it starts working! But this is not a solution, I obviously can't do this in the Live environment.

Comment: What does the callback return for anonymous users? Is it an integer?

Comment: @Jaypan it returns an empty string in all cases and adds a redirect to the response.

Comment: D7 doesn't have the Response class to which redirects can be added. Can you please show your code?

Comment: @jaypan - added the essential parts of the callback, leaving out all the conditional stuff.

Comment: So, weirdly enough, when I turned on Devel and gave anonymous users permission to access debug output, the error page started to be used ....  I obviously can't keep Devel enabled, so I will play some more with what exactly breaks/fixes it.

Comment: And indeed - turned Devel off again and it is back to the status quo. Error page is not recognized/used for anonymous.

Comment: Are you trying to either do a redirect or show a page not found?

Comment: @Jaypan I am doing a redirect. A page not found message is not adequate for a real estate site where content changes daily and search engines frequently serve links to listings that were removed. In these cases, my client wants to handle this more gracefully and present a gentle message with a search screen and other potentially interesting properties.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a switch(), but with only a default for the switch and no options, it means the switch is unnecessary. Drupal also provides the `drupal_goto()` function, which handles both redirects, as well as cancelling killing the script so the redirect can proceed. Your code can be simplified to:

```
function my_customerror_page($code) {
  $dest = variable_get('my_customerror_' . $code . '_default', '');
  drupal_goto($dest);
}
```

Or if you're really set on using `header()` to set headers for whatever reason, you just need to add `drupal_exit()` after your call to `header()`.

Comment: I added a placeholder to the code snippet that makes it more obvious why the switch is there. Granted, it is not relevant for the question or answer and I could have removed it.
drupal_goto does its own path validation, does not work with external URLs, and I just could not get it working with the query string that I need. It did not work for me.

Comment: And thank you for looking into this with me! Much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, and I am not sure calling drupal_exit is the right thing to do here - doesn't this stop the request pipeline? Isn't it better to allow the callback to return and complete in an orderly fashion?

Comment: That's what `drupal_exit()` does. If you don't call it, the rest of the Drupal process runs through before your redirect happens. `drupal_exit()` shuts down the necessary bits, without running the unnecessary bits.

Comment: I did more testing with a lot of permutations of all the variable elements here. Using drupal_exit() does not change anything, so I can't accept your answer. Not setting the response code with header() was the thing that ultimately resolved this, if we want to call it that. It remains a mystery to me why it would matter.

Answer (score -1):

Two subtle changes to the callback function appear to have resolved this. It is working now:

1. returning something other than an empty string
2. using drupal_add_http_header() to set the response code instead of the low
   level PHP function.

As in:

```
function my_customerror_page($code) {
  $dest = variable_get('my_customerror_' . $code . '_default', '');
  drupal_add_http_header('Status', '301 Moved Permanently');
  header("Location: " . $dest);
  return "redirecting ....";
}
```